# Permission Denied on FileSystemObject.CopyFile even as Administrator

Tags: vba, vbscript

So I'm new to Windows Deployments so I may be doing something basic wrong here.  I'm trying to copy a script to a folder in the windows directory during a windows deployment using MDT

Basically what I'm going for is trying to copy a script to the %windir%\temp\deploymentscripts folder but I get permission denied even as admin.  I'll run through what I think I'm doing

```
First, elevate to admin
Create %WinDir%\Temp\DeploymentScripts
Copy DefaultShell.vbs to that directory (this is where I get permission denied
Mount ntuser.dat to the registry
Set DefaultShell.vbs to the Run Once for default users
Unmount ntuser.dat
```

Here's the actual code

```
Option Explicit 

If WScript.Arguments.length = 0 Then
Dim wshShell : Set wshShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
wshShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", """" & _
WScript.ScriptFullName & """" &_
 " RunAsAdministrator", , "runas", 1
Else

Dim objFSO : Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim objShell : Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim TempDir
Dim ParentDir
Dim FullPath
TempDir = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%WinDir%\Temp\DeploymentScripts")

If Not (objFSO.FolderExists(TempDir)) Then
objFSO.CreateFolder (TempDir)
End If

ParentDir = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(Wscript.ScriptFullName)
FullPath = ParentDir & "\DefaultShell.vbs"

objFSO.CopyFile FullPath, TempDir, True

objShell.run "reg load HKU\ZZZ C:\users\default\ntuser.dat"
objShell.RegWrite "HKU\ZZZ\Software\Microsoft\Windows\RunOnce\DefaultShell", _
"WScript.exe" & " " & FullPath, "REG_SZ"
objShell.run "reg unload HKU\ZZZ"

End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

1. The `tempDir` variable was not set right. Add a trailing slash, and this should work. eg:

   `TempDir = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%WinDir%\Temp\DeploymentScripts\")`
2. a. You were pointing to the wrong registry location - you were missing `CurrentVersion`.

   b. The way you are referencing `HKU` In the `regwrite` instruction is likely to cause errors. If it does cause an error, for that line only, change it to read `HKEY_USERS` insdead of `HKU`.

   eg:

   `objShell.RegWrite "HKEY_USERS\ZZZ\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Currentversion\RunOnce\defaultshell", _
   "WScript.exe" & " " & FullPath, "REG_SZ"`
3. To be sure that your script runs in sequence, I've added a couple of `StdOut.ReadAll()` instructions. Without that, the script will continue processing even if you haven't finished loading the hive yet. I guess it just simply tells the script to wait until the `reg` command finishes before moving on to the next instruction.

Here's a revised version of your script, with these suggestions incorporated.

```
Option Explicit 

If WScript.Arguments.length = 0 Then
   Dim wshShell : Set wshShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
   wshShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", """" & _
   WScript.ScriptFullName & """" &_
   " RunAsAdministrator", , "runas", 1

Else

   Dim objFSO : Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Dim objShell : Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   Dim TempDir, ParentDir, FullPath, Regload, Regresp
   TempDir = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%WinDir%\Temp\DeploymentScripts\")

   If Not (objFSO.FolderExists(TempDir)) Then
      objFSO.CreateFolder (TempDir)
   End If

   ParentDir = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(Wscript.ScriptFullName)
   FullPath = ParentDir & "\DefaultShell.vbs"
   objFSO.CopyFile FullPath, TempDir, True

   Set regload = objShell.exec ("reg load HKU\ZZZ C:\users\default\ntuser.dat" )
   regresp = regload.StdOut.ReadAll()

   objShell.RegWrite "HKEY_USERS\ZZZ\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Currentversion\RunOnce\DefaultShell", _
   "WScript.exe" & " " & FullPath, "REG_SZ"

   Set regload = objShell.exec ("reg unload HKU\ZZZ")
   regresp = regload.StdOut.ReadAll()

End If
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  You're amazing!  Something I noticed after testing my deployment however is that the line 
'objShell.RegWrite "HKEY_USERS\ZZZ\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Currentversion\RunOnce\DefaultShell", _
   "WScript.exe" & " " & FullPath, "REG_SZ"'  The FullPath should be TempDir in the Regwrite command - otherwise it looks for the deployment share at first log in.

Now the script gives an error "Execution of the Windows Script Host failed. (Not enough
storage is available to complete this operation. )
"

Comment: Interesting, I ran the script no issues. Can you add a section to your question and repost your modified script, and show which line is generating that error?

Comment: Let me try and clarify.  The code you helped with initially worked perfectly.  The defaultshell.vbs script which is set to run once a new user logs on is that one that throws the error.  That script is
    Dim objShell : Set objSell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
objShell.RegWrite "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ControlPanel\Desktop\Wallpaper", "", "REG_SZ"

Comment: You have written set objsell - is that in your code or is it a typo here?

Comment: I found the error!  Thanks!  I wrote the regkey wrong